# Printing every character of a UTF8 string

Tags: c, string, utf-8, icu

I am new to Unicode/UTF8 representations of strings. I am trying to read a `UTF8` encoded file, separate it with spaces and then print every character/code-point in every word (separated by spaces).

I was able to use `wchar_t` (I know it uses `utf16` or `utf32`(?) internally) for reading text from the file, printing it and writing it to another file. However, I was unable to use the `wchar_t` to get either a substring or traverse it element by element.

To solve for this, I used the `ICU` library from IBM. Code:

```
while (fgetws(readString, 1000, wifile) != NULL) {
        wprintf(L"String: %s\n", readString);
        //split string on the base of spaces.
        wchar_t *nextToken = NULL;
        wchar_t *token = wcstok_s(readString, L" ", &nextToken);
        UChar *utf8Token = (UChar *)token;
        u_printf("Token in UChar: %S\n", utf8Token);
        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("Hello.\n");
            fwprintf(wofileString, L"%ls and length: %d\n", token, wcslen(token));
            fwprintf(wofileString, L"UTF8 rep:%s and length: %d\n", utf8Token, u_strlen(utf8Token));
            int32_t counter = 0;
            for (counter = 0; counter < u_strlen(utf8Token);) {
                UChar32 ch;
                U8_NEXT(utf8Token, counter, u_strlen(utf8Token), ch);
                fwprintf(wofileString, L"Token[%d] = ", counter);
                if (ch < 127) {
                    printf("Less than 127.\n");
                    if (ch > 1) {
                        printf("Printing%d.\n", ch);
                        u_fprintf((UFILE *)wofileString, "%c\n", (UChar)ch);
                    }
                } else if (ch == CharacterIterator::DONE) {
                    printf("Done.\n");
                    u_fprintf((UFILE *)wofileString, "[CharacterIterator::DONE]\n");
                } else {
                    printf("More than 127.\n");
                    u_fprintf((UFILE *)wofileString, "[%X]\n", ch);
                }
            }
            token = wcstok_s(NULL, L" ", &nextToken);
            utf8Token = (UChar *)token;
            counter = 0;
        }
        fputws(L"Complete String: ", wofileString);
        fputws(readString, wofileString);
        fputws(L"\n", wofileString);
    }
```

This program always stops working when it gets to the part where the characters are printed.

My questions:
1. How can I print all the 'characters' in the input UTF8 string?
2. Is the conversion: `UChar *utf8Token = (UChar *) token;` even correct? Given that the internal representation for `token` is `UTF16` or `UTF32`?
3. Where am I going wrong?
4. How do I get a substring of the string?

Comment: Are you sure your code stops? Maybe, your terminal can not display UTF.

Comment: @Matthias: Yes. I am sure it stops. Windows lets you know it stopped. The console cannot display UTF but it does display weird symbols and characters instead.

Answer (score 0):

`fwprintf(wofileString,…
 u_fprintf((UFILE *)wofileString,…`

One of these two lines is wrong, depending on what wofileString actually is.

I'd recommend just using the `u_…` functions.

In fact, I'd just use `u_printf("string", …)` or `u_printf_u(L"String", …)` instead of `fwprintf` or `fputws`.